# Three If statements in while loops

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I have three if statements in my while loop that is supposed to ask questions until the question variable is equal to 10.

However I think because I have three if statements is the reason why it is only asking three questions instead. I have tried to use break - which ends my while loop

This is my code:

```
while question<10: 
user_answer=input(str(random.choice(numbers)) + random.choice(operators) + str(random.choice(numbers1))) 

if operators == '+': 
    expected_answer = numbers + numbers1 
    if user_answer==expected_answer:
        print ('This is correct!') 
        print ("Your score so far is",score,"out of 10") 
        question=question+1 
        time.sleep(2) 
        print ('This is incorrect!') 
        question=question+1 
        time.sleep(2) 

if operators == '-': 
    expected_answer = numbers - numbers1 
    if user_answer==expected_answer: 
        print ('This is correct!') 
        print ("Your score so far is",score,"out of 10") 
        question=question+1 
        time.sleep(2) 
        print ('This is incorrect!') 
        question=question+1 
        time.sleep(2) 

if operators == '*': 
    expected_answer = numbers * numbers1
    if user_answer==expected_answer: 
        print ('This is correct!') 
        score=score+1 
        print ("Your score so far is",score,"out of 10") 
        question=question+1 
        time.sleep(2) 
        print ('This is incorrect!')  
        question=question+1 
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Please indent your code correctly.  Python uses whitespace where other languages use curly brackets.  As it is, it is impossible to determine where the blocks are in your code.  In fact, this shouldn't even run, as the while loop contains no body.

Comment: Why do you repeat yourself that often?

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Does ever `operators` (which is some kind of collection, since you are using `random.choice(operators)`) is equal to SINGLE value? (that what's checked by your `operators == '*'` tests)

Answer (score 0):

```
while question<10: 
   user_answer=input(str(random.choice(numbers)) + random.choice(operators) + str(random.choice(numbers1))) 

   if operators == '+': 
       expected_answer = numbers + numbers1

   if operators == '-': 
      expected_answer = numbers - numbers1

   if operators == '*': 
      expected_answer = numbers * numbers1

   if user_answer==expected_answer:
       score=score+1
       print ('This is correct!')
   else: 
       print ('This is incorrect!')

   print ("Your score so far is",score,"out of 10")
   question=question+1 
   time.sleep(2)
```

Can be done much better, mapping the operators and so. I'll let you do it :)

Answer (score 0):

The loop runs less than 10 times because if the answer is correct, the question variable is increased twice. And both messages ("correct"/"incorrect") are printed. Your code needs 'else':

```
if user_answer==expected_answer:
    print ('This is correct!') 
    print ("Your score so far is",score,"out of 10") 
    question=question+1 
    time.sleep(2) 
else:
    print ('This is incorrect!') 
    question=question+1 
    time.sleep(2)
```

But consider to rewrite the whole code as stated by Anton Epikhin!